# Query de coincidencias no arroja registro

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una query SQL la cual busca en una una tabla de acuerdo a cuatro parámetros o si no hay paraemtros regresa todos los registros de la tabla, el problema es que al buscar un titulo no regresa ningun resultado y se supone que si debe tener coincidencia con algun registro de la tabla sql, creo quetengo erronea mi Query especialmente en el LIKE

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcListarpProyectosEfectivo]
    (   
    @DescripcionProyecto VARCHAR(100) =NULL ,
    @TituloProyecto VARCHAR(50) =NULL ,
    @FechaInicio DATE =NULL ,
    @FechaFin DATE =NULL 
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 
        ID_Proyecto,
        DescripcionProyecto,
        TituloProyecto,
        FechaInicio,
        FechaFin
 FROM PROYECTOS WHERE 
    (DescripcionProyecto like '%@DescripcionProyecto%' OR @DescripcionProyecto IS NULL) AND 
    (TituloProyecto like '%@TituloProyecto%' OR @TituloProyecto IS NULL) AND 
    (FechaInicio=@FechaInicio OR @FechaInicio IS NULL) AND 
    (FechaFin=@FechaFin OR @FechaFin IS NULL) AND       
    (Eliminado <> 1)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC ProcMensajeError 
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
like '%@DescripcionProyecto%'
```

... no está usando el valor dentro de la variable `@DescripcionProyecto`. Mas bien, estás buscando literalmente una cadena `"@DescripcionProyecto"`.

Para usar la variable correctamente, debes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
like '%' + @DescripcionProyecto + '%'
```

Comment: @Patricio: En su caso no tiene mayor importancia, porque en cada caso, él maneja el NULL en la condición que sigue: `OR @DescripcionProyecto IS NULL`.